# Baby Rudin Limit of Logarithmic Function

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

On page 181 of Rudin's *Principles* *of* *Mathematical* *Analysis*, the following statement about the infinite limit of the logarithmic function is given:
[image: p181]

And here is Theorem 8.6(e):
[image: 8.6(e)]

How do I arrive at the conclusion that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}L(x)=+\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}L(x)=-\infty$ from Theorem 8.6(r)?

(In Rudin's notation, $E(x)=\exp x$ and $L(x)=\log x$)

---

Here’s my attempt in the middle of which I am stuck.

First, by definition, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}E(x)=0$ is to say
$$
\forall M.\exists N.\forall x.x<N\implies E(x)<M.
$$
Now take the contrapositive of the inner proposition, we have
$$
\forall M.\exists N.\forall x.E(x)\geq M\implies x\geq N.
$$
Since $L(E(x))=x$, it is possible to write $y=E(x)$ ($y>0$) and rewrite the previous proposition as
$$
\forall M.\exists N.\forall y.(y>0\land y\geq M)\implies L(y)\geq N.
$$
To show $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to+\infty}L(y)=+\infty$, one has to show that
$$
\forall N.\exists M.\forall y.(y>0\land y\geq M)\implies L(y)\geq N;
$$
the order of the quantifier is incorrect.

Here I noticed that the two symbols bound by a universal quantifier and an existential quantifier can be interchanged with a condition:
$$
\forall a\in A.\exists b(a)\in B.P(a,b)\iff\forall b’\in\text{Range}(b).\exists a=b^{-1}(b’).P(a,b’),
$$
where $b(a)$ is a multivalued function (it is defined as a multivalued function in order to capture the case where there exists more than one $b(a)$ satisfying $P$) that denotes the dependency of the existential quantified to the universal quantified and $b^{-1}(b’)$ denotes one arbitrary element of the preimage of $b$ (it is defined so that the injectivity of $b$ is not required, and such choice of element is always possible since $b'\in \text{Range}(b)$).

And here is where I am stuck. To use the fact I discovered for interchanging the order of the quantified symbols to acquire the desired conclusion, one must show that $\text{Range}(N)=\mathbb{R}$ (or at least a neighborhood of positive infinity), and I cannot do that without triggering a circular argument where the conclusion itself is used.

---

Frankly, at this point, I'm considering that my approach may not be the correct approach, or at least not the simplest one, so if you have a better idea, please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved through another method.

The goal is to prove
$$
\forall M.\exists N.y>N\implies L(y)>M.
$$

By the monotonicity of $E(x)$,
$$
\left(\forall x_1,x_2.x_1\geq x_2\implies E(x_1)\geq E(x_2)\right)\implies\left(\forall x_1,x_2.E(x_1)<E(x_2)\implies x_1<x_2\right).
$$

For $y_1<y_2$, represent it with
$$
y_1=E(x_1)<E(x_2)y_2
$$
where
$$
x_1<x_2
$$
by previous argument. Thus
$$
L(y_1)=L(E(x_1))=x_1<x_2=L(E(x_2))=L(y_2)
$$

Take $N=E(M)$, then by the monotonicity of $L$ we have
$$
y>E(M)\implies L(y)>L(E(M))\geq M,
$$
as desired.